# How to deal with non normality of residuals in VECM?

Tags: residuals, normality-assumption, cointegration, diagnostic, vector-error-correction-model

Does anyone know how to handle non normality of residuals in VECM? I have tried transforming the data into log, exp, and Box-cox but nothing has changed. Any suggestion will do. Thank you.